# CSV deletes the data from the table

Tags: sql

I have created a new table in SQLPro for Postgres, and I want to upload multiple CSV into that Table.

Each CSV has about 5K records. Basically, whenever I want to upload another one it deletes/overrides the information from the table.

Can you help? :)

Comment: please describe the issue you are facing using a [minimal reproducible  example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Basically,

1. Merge all the CSV with the headers insert them into your table.
2. Delete all the rows that were created by headers.

Might be obvious, but remember it will only work with CSV where data is mapped the same way.